# How do I centre an image inside of a div element (HTML)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple tic-tac-toe application using HTML, CSS, Javascript.

I've set the X and O images in HTML like so:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
      <img src="X.png" alt="X" id="X">
      <img src="O.png" alt="O" id="O">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="X.png" alt="X" id="X">
      <img src="O.png" alt="O" id="O">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="X.png" alt="X" id="X">
      <img src="O.png" alt="O" id="O">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="X.png" alt="X" id="X">
      <img src="O.png" alt="O" id="O">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="X.png" alt="X" id="X">
      <img src="O.png" alt="O" id="O">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="X.png" alt="X" id="X">
      <img src="O.png" alt="O" id="O">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="X.png" alt="X" id="X">
      <img src="O.png" alt="O" id="O">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="X.png" alt="X" id="X">
      <img src="O.png" alt="O" id="O">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="X.png" alt="X" id="X">
      <img src="O.png" alt="O" id="O">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using CSS grid to arrange each div in my HTML as a cell (inside the X and O will show up).

```
  <style>
    .wrapper{
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns:100px 100px 100px;
      grid-template-rows:100px 100px 100px;
      grid-gap:10px;
    }

    .wrapper > div{
      background:#eee;
      padding:1em;
    }

    #X{
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
    }

    #O{
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
    }

  </style>
```

The resulting web page looked like this:

[image: tic-tac-toe]

Now as you can see, the X and O aren't centered inside each of their respective boxes. My intention is to make X and O overlap on top of each other (so that I can use javascript to enable and disable their visibility later on). I initially thought I could solve this problem via margin or padding. So I set the left-padding for the X images like this:

```
#X{
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
      padding-left: 16px
    }
```

This successfully centered the X image in each box on the horizontal axis.

[image]

However, when I tried to add padding-top to X (to centre it vertically), X went back to its initial position (as seen in the first image).

So how would I centre the X (and eventually, the O) in their respective boxes?

Comment: Incidentally, all `id`s must be unique to be valid HTML. It looks like you meant to use `class="X"` (etc.) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by taking advantage of the `relative` and `absolute` positioning. Using these along with `transform` will nicely overlap and center each of of your images in the grid.

Just to note; you're using `id="X"` on multiple elements. ID's need to be unique and so you can't use the same one more than once - I've replaced these with classes in the snippet below.

```css
.wrapper{
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns:100px 100px 100px;
      grid-template-rows:100px 100px 100px;
      grid-gap:10px;
    }

    .wrapper > div{
      background:#eee;
      padding:1em;
      position:relative;
    }

    .X, .O {
      position:absolute;
      top:50%;
      left:50%;
      transform:translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0)
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/50/50/animals" alt="X" class="X">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/50/50/arch" alt="O" class="O">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/50/50/animals" alt="X" class="X">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/50/50/arch" alt="O" class="O">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution worked. However, I managed to create the desired affect by removing the line `transform:translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0)` and setting both `top` and `left` to 25%. What's the point of using `transform:translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0)` if I can just use `top` and `left`? Aren't they both technically translating the element position?

Comment: Furthermore, since I plan on controlling the visibility of each X and O individually (based on user input), do you think it would be a good idea to give each X and O a unique id instead of class (for example: X_topleft, O_topleft, X_topright, etc.)? Or is there a simpler way around this?

Comment: And using `top:25%;` and `left:25%` won't center everything perfectly, whereas setting them as `50%` and then using the `translate` function will do. See these two examples of **[Setting top to 25%](https://jsfiddle.net/hevu6ozg/)** vs **[Transform3d](https://jsfiddle.net/a7ghy0kc/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2 elements to overlap with each other you should give them `position: absolute;` Also you should make a div around it which has `position: relative;`

```css
.column{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.column img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
   <img src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/99-992857_inner-page-closing-comments-tic-tac-toe-x.png" alt="X" id="X">
   <img src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/letter-o-png-open-2000.png" alt="O" id="O">
</div>
```

But in your code you should make it so both elements are on `display: none;`, this way it wont use any space until you make the element `display: block;`
Since only 1 element will be `display: block;` at the time you want have to worry about overlapping images.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.wrapper > div{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: column;  /* <-- if you want the images to be under each other*/
}
```